# The correct usage of "I've had enough..." with the Gerund

Tags: grammaticality

Willing to express clearly that someone is fed up with something, using the adverb "enough", I couldn't discern the difference between the following variants and therefore I can't tell which of them are correct from a grammatical point of view (maybe they don't even mean the same):

1. I've had enough missing her! I'm wrapping it up!
2. I've had enough ***with*** missing her! I'm wrapping it up!
3. I've had enough ***of*** missing her! I'm wrapping it up!
4. I've had it with missing her! I'm wrapping it up! *(does this phrase have the same meaning as №№. 1, 2, 3?)*

Or, maybe I should have inserted the pronoun ***"it"*** after "had" in №№ 1, 2, 3 (like "I've had it enough...)?

Answer (score 1):

The structure is **'have had enough (of somebody/something)'.** So, you can perfectly say/write 'I've had enough **of** missing her'.

See [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-had-enough-of-something)

'I've had it with missing her' is also correct. You can use the idiom **have had it with something/someone** to express that you'are not enthusiastic about dealing with the same situation.

See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/have-had-it-with)

Comment: Thank you. Is any appreciable distinction in the meaning of "I've had enough of missing her" and "I've had it with missing her" to be drawn out?

Comment: @Eugene In your context no there's none.